# R - Web Scraping

Tags: r, web, web-scraping

First many thanks for your help and your consideration,

I want to extract something from this page http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6875970/keywords Once you are one the website, I am interested in web scraping the information related to

- IEEE Keywords
- INSPEC: Controlled Indexing
- INSPEC: Non-Controlled Indexing

  install.packages("rvest")
  library(rvest)
  keywords<-read_html("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6875970/keywords")

  keywords %>%
  a<-html_node(lego_movie,"text/javascript") %>%
  html_text(a)

But it does not work !

Can you please help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you be a little more specific than *"But it does not work !"*

Comment: Yes course!  What I want is to extract all keywords from the website like Geospatial analysis,Decision making, ... But when I execute my few lines of codes, what I did, it is  "Error in tokenize(css) : Unexpected character '/' found at position 5". Therefore, I am afraid of my code did not fit what I expect . Because I am R beginner and looked at some R tutorials (Lego_movies but it is written in HTLM). If i am not wrong, my webpage is written in JavaScript. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I considered re-formatting this for you, but you've at least got something weird going on with `%>% a <-` which should never happen. That aside, the site you are hoping to scrape has terms of use... "Guest/Member users are NOT permitted to do the following: [...] *Transmit electronically, via e-mail or any other file transfer protocols, any portion of IEEE Xplore.* You may want to consider whether or not you're allowed to use this information once you have it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# if you get an error while importing, just use install.packages('jsonlite') and /or install.packages('stringr')
library(jsonlite) 
library(stringr) 

# the ieee doc url we're interested in
url <- 'http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6875970/keywords'

# read the document as text, no HTML parsing at all
doc <- readLines(url)

# after inspecting it, we notice it's built with angular-js,
# and the data we need to extract is defined as a single javascript variable.

# so, we first find the id of the line which defines 
# the javascript variable containing the tags
idx <- which(!is.na(str_match(doc, 'global.document.metadata=')))

# get the line ;-)
line <- doc[idx]

# since it's a javascript variable, we need to massage it
# a little to be able to read it as json.
# step 1: remove the "var global.document.metadata=" part (everything before the actual json)
line <- str_replace(line, '^[^{]*', '')

# step 2: remove the trailing ';' symbol
line <- str_replace(line, ';$', '')

# now we can parse the json data
df <- fromJSON(line)

# and get the information we need
df$keywords[df$keywords$type == 'IEEE Keywords',]$kwd[[1]]

df$keywords[df$keywords$type == 'INSPEC: Controlled Indexing',]$kwd[[1]]

df$keywords[df$keywords$type == 'INSPEC: Non-Controlled Indexing',]$kwd[[1]]
```

sample output:

```
[1] "CTC incident datasets"                             
[2] "proactive spatiotemporal resource allocation"      
[3] "predictive visual analytics"                  
[4] "community policing"                               
[5] "law enforcement"
```

Comment: It works !!! Thanks a lot Leonardo Foderaro ! You are the best !!!! And moreover it is super-clear !

Comment: Really thank you ! Very very helpful ! Please let me know if one day I can help you in the field of finance or statistics :)

Comment: (I didn't mention finance because it's by far out of my skills lol)

Comment: Leonardo can you send me an email?  I have a question which I think you can answer.  rms7272 at gmail.com
Just replace that at with @

Comment: Hi Ryan, I just sent you a mail with subject "contact from StackOverflow".